# How do I fetch the price from this page using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the price(i.e. $152) from this [page](https://www.dianeslingerie.com/product/serie-piana-short-sleeve-tunic-by-mey/). I have tried different combination of tags within the find_all method but all I am getting is empty list. What am I doing wrong?

```
u = 'https://www.dianeslingerie.com/product/serie-piana-short-sleeve-tunic-by-mey/'
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
soup.find_all('div', {'class':'summary-container'})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dianeslingerie.com/product/serie-piana-short-sleeve-tunic-by-mey/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'woocommerce-Price-amount amount'})

print(price.text)
```

To achieve that, you might want to inspect the page and look for a class, an id or a html tag that is unique to the object you want to scrape.

In this case, the 'woocommerce-Price-amount amount' class only appears in the price of the page: [image: Screenshot of the page showing the html tags]

As we can see, it is inside a span tag, so we use it along with the class we found before and we get the following output:

```
$152.00
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot of times even if I am trying with correct class, it isn't returning anything.
For example in the given if I want to grab the item name, I should get it in 'h1' tag with class 'product_title entry-title fusion-responsive-typography-calculated'.
But I am getting nothing. Could you tell why?

Comment: to be honest, i don't know why it's returning none, but i could achieve it doing in another way:
`name = soup.find('div', {'class': 'summary-container'}).find('h1')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4
import requests
u = 'https://www.dianeslingerie.com/product/serie-piana-short-sleeve-tunic-by-mey/'
r = requests.get(u)
c = r.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
price = soup.find("span", {"class": "woocommerce-Price-amount amount"})
print(price.get_text()) # $152.00
```